# How to include a string value in SharedPreferences into a url code to launch a pdf file?

Tags: java, android

How to include a string value in SharedPreferences into a url code to launch a pdf file? what am I missing?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_load);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    setContentView(webview);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(contentPreferencess, 0);


    String myPdfUrl =  (settings.getString(contentPreferencess, "fileURL"));;
    String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;
    webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Basically i want to load a url which is in the sharedPreferences into the String myPdfUrl so thgat the app wll load the pdf file..

Activity 1 is where all the values are kept>  Activity 2 pulls values from sharedPreferences for text view and there's a button..> Activity 3 is supposed to load the pdf file upon clicking the button in the previous activity

Comment: what is contentPreferencess? Make sure it is holding key for the url string value in the sharedPref. Also please add the code where you storing value in sharedPreferences

Comment: The key is "fileURL" and the value is the weblink where the pdf file is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
String myPdfUrl =  (settings.getString(contentPreferencess, "fileURL"));;
```

to

```
String myPdfUrl =  settings.getString("fileURL");
```

OR

```
 String myPdfUrl =  settings.getString("fileURL","DefaultValueIFYOUNEED");
```

Comment: first also works...for you the second worked that means any string value with key as fileURL is not present in the sharedpreference...Please make sure key is similar when you used to save the string value in the sharedpreference